# golang return function and assigned value

Tags: go

I am going to learn 'golang return function' but I'm seriously confused.
why this code return "7" ?
how the value is assigned to "y" ?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func maked(x float64) func(float64) float64 {

    fn := func(y float64) float64 {
        return x - y

    }
    return fn
}

func main() {
    test := maked(12)

    fmt.Println(test(5))
    // printed 7
}
```

Comment: `test(5)` calls `test` with `5` assigned to `y`.

Comment: What would you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`test := maked(12)` returns a function like below.

```
   fn := func(y float64) float64 {
        return 12 - y

    }
```

and now test have that function. So `test(5)` runs above function with `y = 5`.
so `12 - 5 = 7`